# Declaring int object in c++

Tags: c++, object, int, declaration

I am new to C++ and I am solving some easy exercises. I was solving one problem when I came across a behavior that I cannot explain.

My function takes 2 arrays as arguments and I must return sum of all elements in these arrays. My code:

```
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int arrayPlusArray(vector<int> a, vector<int> b){
    int c=0;
    for (auto k : a){
        c += k;}
    for (auto k : b){
        c += k;}
    return c;
}
```

This works, but as soon as I write `int c;` instead of `int c=0;` it does not work correctly anymore. I thought that when I write `int c;` it sets `c`'s value to `0`. What is the matter?

Comment: Maybe you should conclude from this that you thought wrong?

Comment: You need to initialise variable to use.

Comment: static and global variables are initialized for you since there is no runtime overhead to default  initializing, the same is not true of variables with automatic storage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Writing `int c;` does **not** initialise `c` (unless `c` is at global scope or has `static` storage). Initialisation costs CPU clock cycles so C++ allows the programmer to forgo such unnecessary CPU expenditure at the expense of potential program instability.

In fact, the behaviour on *reading* an uninitialised variable is *undefined* (unless it's a `char`, an `signed char` or an `unsigned char`) in C++. **Never** do it.